# My heatmap is not printing all the values , its just printing the 1st row

Tags: heatmap

[image]

My code was working fine but then I ran few codes like pip install matplotlib dask pdpbox
and uninstalled and installed matplotlib a nos of times and then my heatmap stopped showing values

I tried upgrading the matplolib

I have python 3.12.0 version, matplotlib, 3.8.3 and also tried 3.8.0 and searbon 0.13.2